# ttl 3.3v but almost 0 amps, max232 does not send anything at 12v

Tags: amplifier, ttl

Here I have basic board which has ttl serial working on 3.3v (yes I measured it) but it does not have any amps, it barely can light up pore led diode, with my meter it shows 0 micro amps current with led as load. The led light up only when its connected directly to board pins so what i can do to boost current on this ttl so so it could talk to max232

Many tnx cheers :)

Comment: What are the input currents Iil and IiH OF Max232? How is 3.3 signal being generated?

Comment: Input current for max 232 I tried 3,3 from arduino its about 500mA and 5v 1A from wall adapter, same deal, max 232 working just fine with other boards like my tp-link router

Comment: If you were able to light up a LED barely, you can burn MAX232. There is something missing

Answer (score 1):

Put a CMOS driver after it such as a 74LVCxG34 (x=1, 2, or 3) or 74HC125/126 that can provide a much stronger drive from the weak incoming signal.

Comment: Ok will try one of those, I dont know what I will found at local store hope that will be 74HC125/126 Tnx for suggestion cheers